# Symfony : relation with multiple entiy types

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I am building an application where a User can have relation with multiple kind of entities : skills, tools, styles.

Those relations contain extra info like a rating.

My user entity will have three different attributes (skills, tools, styles) but I would like to use the same intermediary table for each of those relations.

I plan to build something like that :

**User**

- Name
- ...
- Tools
- Skills
- Style

**UserRates**

- User id
- Tool/style/skill id
- Relation type ("tool", "style", "skill")
- Rate

**Tools**

- Name
- ...

**Skills**

- Name
- ...

**Styles**

- Name
- ...

---

Another similar scenario would be to build a system to rate anything (blog posts, events, images, ...).
I can't imagine a system where you have to rebuild the relation for each new notable entity.

---

My questions are:

- Is this kind of relation is doable in SF2?
- Do you know any good example / article?
- How would you do it ? I guess I need a custom repository and custom setters/getters ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: I have already built relations but this is the first time I am in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**Tools**

Entities are handled by an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). I'm guessing you're using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) as it comes standard with Symfony2+.

**How to do relationships**

Relations are done with Doctrine mappings which you can find here [on their documentation website](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).

*Note:* the annotations in the doctrine documentation do not have the `@ORM/` prefix, which Entities which are part of Symfony2 require (look at "use" statments to see why). So you'll have to add them yourself.

**PS:** Unless you have *very* good reason to relate all those entities via one intermediary table, don't do it.

I should also note that when dealing with an ORM you should not be thinking about tables, but about objects. Doctrine will generate an intermidiary table for ManyToMany relationsips automatically. 
You'll only need to create one yourself (and thus have ManyToOne IntermidiaryEntity OneToMany relationships) when the relation has to carry extra information.

As someone has already suggested, I suggest reading the [relevant chapter in Symfony2's amazing book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

Comment: My bad, I do use doctrine and entities.